# How to plot least squares regression cost function as contour plot in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, contour

I am trying to learn some basic machine learning. I have implemented gradient descent, however I am trying to visualize my cost function but am stuck on how to do that.

Below is my cost function

w is a 2 x 1 array (what most people label as theta) that represents the slope and y intercept of a line (w[0, 1] = slope, w[1, 1] = y int)

X is a 400 x 2 array. The first column is the actual data, the second 
column is a column of all 1's.

t is the true y value (400 x 1 array)

```
def cost_fn(w, X, t):
    N, M = np.shape(X)
    y = X @ w
    difference = t - y
    return np.sum(np.square(difference)) / (2.0 * N)
```

This works fine with my gradient descent algorithm.

However, I am trying to make a contour plot of my cost function with cost on the z axis and w[0, 1] and w[1, 1] on the x and y axes of the contour plot.

My first attempt involved generating a matrix of various w vectors, storing each of those vectors in a array of column vectors, looping through them, and calculating cost for each of those w vectors and using those as my Z values

```
def cost_array(w, X, t):

    nrow_w, ncol_w = w.shape
    cost = np.zeros((ncol_w, 1))

    for i in range(0, ncol_w):
        y = X @ w[:, i]

        cost_i = cost_fn(w[:, i], X, t)
        cost[i, 0] = cost_i
    print(cost)
    return cost

w1 = np.array([np.linspace(-40, 40, num=1000)])
w0 = np.array([np.linspace(-40, 40, num=1000)])
w_array = np.vstack((w1, w0))
# print(w_array)
x_msh, y_msh = np.meshgrid(w1,w0)
c_array = cost_array(w_array, X, t)
plt.contour(x_msh, y_msh, c_array, cmap='RdGy')
plt.show()
```

However contour is complaining that my c_array is not of at least 2x2 shape. How can I remedy this? Also is there a way of vectorizing my cost_array function so that I dont have to use the loop?

Here is a full example:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def generate_data():
     x = np.arange(400)
     delta = np.random.uniform(-10,10, size=(400,))
     y = .4 * x +3 + delta
     return x, y

def cost_fn(w, X, t):
    N, M = np.shape(X)
    y = X @ w
    difference = t - y
    return np.sum(np.square(difference)) / (2.0 * N)

def cost_array(w, X, t):

    nrow_w, ncol_w = w.shape
    cost = np.zeros((ncol_w, 1))

    for i in range(0, ncol_w):
        y = X @ w[:, i]

        cost_i = cost_fn(w[:, i], X, t)
        cost[i, 0] = cost_i

    return cost

x, t = generate_data()

x = x[:, None]
t = t[:, None]

# add col of 1s to X
ones_array = np.ones(x.shape[0])
X = np.c_[x, ones_array]

# Example of w vector
w = np.array([[1, 1]]).T
print(w)

# Example of cost function:
cost_example = cost_fn(w, X, t)

# Trying to make contour
w1 = np.array([np.linspace(-40, 40, num=1000)])
w0 = np.array([np.linspace(-40, 40, num=1000)])
w_array = np.vstack((w1, w0))

x_msh, y_msh = np.meshgrid(w1,w0)
c_array = cost_array(w_array, X, t)
plt.contour(x_msh, y_msh, c_array, cmap='RdGy')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: can you provide the expression for X and t that are used in the line

c_array = cost_array(w_array, X, t)

Comment: added some sample data